# Inserting a value with a comma ( , ) into a database using PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values with a comma into a database but the comma is splitting the query so that the part of the string before the comma goes into the correct column, while the bit after the comma goes into the next and every item in the query after that is displaced into the next column.

My connection file to my db is as follows:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', '********');
define('DB_USER', '********');
define('DB_PASS', '********');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct() {}
    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function instance(){
        if (self::$instance === null){
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args){
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = []){
        if (!$args){
            return self::instance()->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

And then I do my query like this:

```
$item1 = 'item1';
$item2 = 'item_with_a_,_symbol';
$item3 = 'item3';

$params = [$item1,$item2,$item3];
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
```

In this case my database would be like so:

```
col1            col2            col3
item1           item_with_a_    _symbol
```

What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: `my database would be` Have you tested this ?

Comment: `item_with_a_,_symbol` - I think you're not telling us the full story here. Is there a symbol going in there? and if so, what is it? I don't understand what you want to do here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the symbol is a comma as in &#44; this means it's splitting that parameter into two variables

Comment: @PaddyHallihan what you mentioned above in a comment to me, think that should have been part of the question. Where is that coming from anyway?

Comment: If you use parameterized queries you do not have to worry about such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the input before running the insert. 
[`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) should do the trick

[Check this entry](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in the PHP manual for reference

Comment: You don't need to escape paremeters to prepared statements.